# Open Gradle Project in Netbeans 12

Tags: gradle, netbeans, netbeans-12

When i open a gradle project in Netbeans 12 i have this message:

"Project Problems: Priming Build Required"
"Description: In order to be able to read this project, NetBeans needs to execute its Gradle scripts as priming build.Executing Gradle scripts allows arbitrary code execution, as current user, on this system."
(My gradle project works without Netbeans IDE.)
What means this? I want more details.
Netbeans version: 12
Gradle version: 6.5
Java Version: 14.0.2

Comment: I have the same issue :( Have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to check down right "unread notification" [You have (1) unread notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVStV.png)

For me the problem was with test dependency that was as SNAPSHOT version.
e.g. testImplementation ("com.company:some-package:1.10-SNAPSHOT")
Then the error was:
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 31: com.company\some-package:1.10-SNAPSHOT\20201124.210844-10

After solving this issue (changed dependency),
testImplementation ("com.company:some-package:1.10.0")
the project was loaded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it's due to dependency issue. To fix dependency issue I

- upgrade the gradle version.
- add missing imports in build.gradle